# quick java question

Tags: java, stack

im currently learning stacks in java and have a quick question. what will the following code display if the stack is empty? my guess would be "true"?

```
System.out.println(st.isEmpty());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it will print `true`.

Running simple snippets of code is very easy (with IDEs like Eclipse - even easier), so you can verify all such assumptions with a few clicks/keystrokes.

Comment: im having trouble using eclipse, cant seem to find the compile button.

Comment: @mark: Then you should read a tutorial. Others managed to use Eclipse, so can you!

Comment: eclipse has a "run" button/menu option. It compiles files automatically (by default)

Comment: There is no compile button in eclipse (except for the build option in the project menu) The code is compiled automatically every time you save your current file.

Comment: But it doesn't save the file automatically (last I used it, anyway) so be sure to save first.

Comment: -1 outright answering a pretty obvious homework/test question.

Comment: @Bill K it is never said "don't answer easy questions" + I not only answered him, but told him how to answer such questions himself next time.

Comment: Not so much easy as an obvious test/homework question--I'd hope people could use a little intuition to see that something so trivial is probably being read off a test paper and typed into a phone somewhere.

Comment: @Bill K - good point about the phone. Will have it in mind hereafter

Answer (score 0):

In the future, give .jpage files a try. They provide a way in Eclipse to run small snippets of code as though they were being interpreted!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test out small snippets of code, try http://ideone.com!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it will simply return true.
IsEmpty() method will return true, if no objects is available in stack container.

```
Stack s1 = new Stack();
    s1.push(1);
    s1.push(2);
    s1.push(3);

    s1.pop();
    s1.pop();
    s1.pop();
    System.out.println(s1.isEmpty());
```